# Speed up query with multiple conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have a sql table of 5,000,000 entries with 5 columns over which I need to make a 4-condition (TEXT type) select. The table has columns id, name, street, city, zip and my select looks like this

`SELECT id FROM register WHERE name=%s AND zip=%s AND city=%s AND street=%s`

Problem is, i need to speed up this query, because i need to do 80 000 of this queries and now it takes half a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%s` placeholders imply that all four of your columns are varchar or text.  If so, then the following index might help:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON register (name, zip, city, street, id)
```

The first four parts of the index cover the `WHERE` clause, and the fifth part covers the `id` column which is needed for the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Better would be an index on `(name, zip, city, street) INCLUDE (id)` if you want an index only scan (from v11 on).